# MDX Multi Level Select

Tags: mdx

I have

```
Geography Dimension
       -> Admin Hierarchy
          -> Province level
          -> District level
          -> Facility level.
```

Now I want to find the geography data when province = 'BeiJing' and facility = 'test'. How should I do ? 
I write MDX code like this:

```
        SELECT
        {} ON 0,
        {[Geography.Admin].[BeiJing].[All Geography.Admin].[test]} ON 1
FROM [EIDCube]
```

but It doesn't work. How can I get all province/district/facility data as table when I set special province and facility ?

Comment: the names you have supplied for your structure do not match the names in your query! you say `Admin Hierarchy` so I would expect a hierarchy called `[Admin]` but in the script it says `[Geography.Admin]` whereas I would expect `[Geography].[Admin]`

Comment: Hi Angela. Did any of us help you in any way? We all spent time trying to help  - do you have time to feed back to our answers?

Answer (score 0):

In `AdvWrks` the following throws an error

> Query (4, 5) The Customer Geography hierarchy is used more than once
>   in the Crossjoin function.

This is thrown when I try to run the following:

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON 0
 ,
    [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country]
  * 
    [Customer].[Customer Geography].[State-Province] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

The way around this is to use the attribute hierarchies which the levels of the `[Customer Geography]` user hierarchy is made up of, like this:

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON 0
 ,
    [Country].[Country]
  * 
    [State-Province].[State-Province] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Now if I want `Australia` and `Queensland` I can cross-join a couple of single member sets:

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON 0
 ,
    {[Country].[Country].[Australia]}
  * 
    {[State-Province].[State-Province].[Queensland]} ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Results in this:

[image]

---

**Edit**

Applying the above to your structure you should be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[someMeasureInCube]} ON 0
 ,
  {[Province].[Province].[BeiJing]} 
* {[Facility].[Facility].[test]} ON 1
FROM [EIDCube];
```

Comment: @AngelaTian this technique _Works_ - the script I showed using `AdvWrks` is a fully tested script - please adapt to your environment. I do not know your exact environment as your initial question does not give enough detail, so my last script is partial guess-work. Please add a screenprint from SSMS to your initial question so we can all see the exact names of your hierarchies and levels.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your hierarchichal structure to be

```
Geography-->Geography.Admin-->Province-->District-->Facility
(dimension) (hierarchy)       (level 1)  (level 2)  (level 3)
```

Here is the MDX to do it the long way(short way being directly feeding the values in query, which surprisingly didn't work)

```
select [Geography].[Geography.Admin].CHILDREN 
    having 
        [Geography].[Geography.Admin].currentmember.member_caption = "test" and
        ancestors([Geography].[Geography.Admin].currentmember, 3).item(0).member_caption = "BeiJing"
    on 1,
{} on 0
from EIDCube]
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use this :

```
SELECT
        {} ON 0,
        ([Geography].[Admin].[BeiJing],[Geography].[Admin].[Province].[District].[test]) ON 1
FROM [EIDCube]
```

**Edit 1 :** My previous answer was wrong.

So now I think the better solution is to create a new hierarchy *[admin2]* for the geography dimension composed of the level *[Facility]* only and to use this query.

```
SELECT
        {} ON 0,
        ([Geography].[Admin].[BeiJing],[Geography].[Admin2].[Facility].[test]) ON 1
FROM [EIDCube]
```

Comment: @polux2 you have just tried to create a tuple of two members from the same hierarchy - how could this ever work?